# what is the best way to make 'back to previous page' system?

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, facelets, back

In my web application, where presentation tier is in JSF, i want to have button
'back to previous page' on some pages.

I'm making it through URL parameters:
`http://www.example.com/index.xhtml?backurl=value`

for example, in mange bean i set current page A.xhtml url:

```
public String showCourse(Course c){
    currentCourse = c;
    String currentUrl = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return "/B.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&backurl=" + currentUrl;
}
```

and at B.xhtml (with url `http://www.example.com/A.xhtml?backurl=A.xhtml`)
i have

```
<h:button value="Back to previous page" outcome="#{backurl}"/>
```

which redirect me to previous page.

Everything works fine, but the problem is when i redirect from B.xhtlm page to C.xhtml page. I set `backurl` url parameter again. After go to C.xhtml page and come back to B.xhtml i lose previous `backurl` parameter - when i click to button i don't come back to A.xhtml page but to C.xhtml :(

Do you know beter why to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's quite awkward there are two ways I can think of.

The first one stems upon a 'linear flow' assumption, under which you have a predefined sequence of views to be presented to the user, as in a flow or conversation, and the current back URL depends on the current view id. So you are supposed to have an application scoped bean with a map of back URLs where the key would be the source view and the destination view (as pointed at by the back button) would be the value. Then, you can define back button outcomes basing on the current view id:

```
@ApplicationScoped @ManagedBean
public class BackUrlBean implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> map;//getter+setter
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String from = ... , back = ...;
        Map.put(from, to);//fill the map
    }
}
```

Then you can have a following structure in your flow:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty backUrlBean.map[view.viewId]}">
    <h:button value="Back to previous page" outcome="#{backUrlBean.map[view.viewId}"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

That's good as soon as you have a linear tree of your flow and a predefined set of pages.

Another viable option is to pass a JSON-serialized list of back URLs instead of a plain back URL. In this approach you'll add an element to the list when next page is requested and user proceeds further in the flow and you'll remove an element from the list when user clicks back. Then the last list element is your current back URL. From-to JSON serialization is performed in a postconstruct method by means of, say Gson.

But beware that get query parameters can be limited in size due to server limitations, so this approach is feasible in case you have not-so-deep flows. Also, don't forget to URL-encode the list as you pass it as a query parameter in your action method.

Advantage of this approach is its generality. Implementation of this approach is left for your practice.

That said, back button must be a back button and it should take user to the previously requested page. Otherwise you may end up with poor user experience.

In my opinion, these forward-back views could be simulated with a wizard-like component containing the navigational buttons. The approach with the back buttons is possible for two-page views like master-detail pages, but not for the flow with a more complex structure.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the browser history and let the user use the browser's back and forward buttons? One can hardly restrict the user to to so anyway. Of course, the web app design needs to support this behaviour.

Comment: if i will use this mechanism is there any way to disable redirect in browser from some pages? how can i make it ?